# TCP network throughput measurement

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am writing a small program to test network throughput as part of an exercise and need to increase the sending and receiving buffers to 256 KB (to try and boost TCP performance). I am doing this with `setsockopt()` and the SO_SNDBUF/SO_RCVBUF options and have also increased the 'net.core.rmem_max' and 'net.core.wmem_max' values.

The getsockopt() confirms the increase in the buffer sizes (double the 256KB value) so I know this is fine. However when I send 256KB of data from one host to another the receiver is always receiving it in several reads each of varying size (form somewhere between 20 to 40 reads ranging in number of received bytes form 1448 to 18824) until it receives all the data. I pretty confused at this point mainly with these questions,

1. With the increased buffer size shouldn't it receive it in one read?
2. Also why do the amount of bytes in each read differ so much (shouldnt they be more of less constant)?
3. Is there some way to ensure the 256KB is received in one read?

Below is the receiver side snippet showing the read part,

```
  while(1) {
    memset(&client_addr, 0, sizeof(client_addr));
    if ((connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &socklen)) <= 0) {
      perror("accept()");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((n = recv(connfd, &buff[0], BUFF_SIZE, 0/*MSG_WAITALL*/)) > 0) {
      totalBytes += n;
      ++pktCount;
      printf("Received(%d): %d bytes\n", pktCount, n);
    }

    if (n == 0) {
      printf("Connection closed (Total: %lu bytes received)\n", totalBytes);
    }

    close(connfd);
    connfd = -1;
    totalBytes = 0;
    pktCount = 0;
  }
```

Any help would be great.

TIA

Comment: [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit#Table_of_MTUs_of_common_media). ACK packets need to sent back too.

Comment: TCP is a stream-oriented protocol, not a datagram one. The amount of data that you get with each read depends on the MSS (which depends on the network MTU) and the TCP window size. That's why message-oriented protocols, that run over a single TCP connection, usually use additional data framing, e.g. each message is prepended by its length so that the reader knows when to stop reading data from the socket, related to the current message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With the increased buffer size shouldn't it receive it in one read?

No. TCP/IP is a streaming protocol and fragments data over a smaller packets. The buffer size primarily affects how much memory an underlying network layer implementation can use (and Linux generally doubles what you have set), but there is no guarantee that receives will receive data in chunks of exactly the same size as sender was sending it (after all, when you call `send()/write()`, it doesn't mean the packet was sent, actually. Also, you are most likely have your packets split anyway due to the [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit).

> Also why do the amount of bytes in each read differ so much (shouldnt they be more of less constant)?

You may want to debug as to why this is happening. There are hundreds of factors — NIC in use, its settings, its driver, TCP/IP, TCP, Ethernet network layer settings, stuff in between sender and receiver (i.e. a switch) etc. But hey, more data comes in while your OS and the application is processing the previous chunk. Given a fact that passing data from the NIC to the user-space application is relatively very expensive, it is not surprising that data is being buffered and you get it in different sizes.

> Is there some way to ensure the 256KB is received in one read?

There might be. One might use a blocking `read()` and require OS to wake up the process only upon receiving at least 256KB or if the error occurs.

Comment: "One might use a blocking `read()` and require OS to wake up the process only upon receiving at least 256KB or if the error occurs." I'm very interested to learn how one can do that.

Comment: Well the MSG_WAITALL flag does that (on my Linux box at least).

Answer (score 2):

You'll have about 180 packets of data to send, which is not anywhere near a lot of data. [Nagle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) will cause arbitrary amounts  of packets to be buffered by either OS, while sending and while receiving.

The trigger for when any buffered packets will be presented through `recv()` is up to the implementation. It might very well present all packets after a certain amount of time, or after a certain amount of internal buffer size is reached. On some OS'es, you can alter those levels using the `SO_RCVLOWAT` socket option.

Comment: I'd like to upvote this, but it needs more information. While it covers some good points it doesn't really answer OPs questions like the other answer does.

Comment: @Joshua it doesn't directly answer the OP's question because not only is the answer four years old and we've all learned a lot in the meantime, but mainly because the proper answer is _"Optimal buffer sizes vary per network and platform, benchmark it"_. Explaining what could cause these variances would not fit in a single answer.

Comment: Exactly, but...the only way someone asking this question is going to know "why" this occurs, is if it is properly explained (even at a high level) so that the way these processes work can be understood. You don't tell someone that "you can't fry a chicken because it's not prepared" and then go on to not explain what kind of preparation is needed. The process while it maybe complicated at a lower level isn't that difficult to convey at a higher one. Please take a look at @user405725 's answer to see how they address the OPs misconceptions about the process to better explain "what happens".

Comment: @Joshua this answer is four years old. If you like the other answer better, upvote that one. Currently I don't really feel inclined to expand this one, because it will be a lot of work for very little, as it will still only scratch the surface of everything you need to know. In retrospect perhaps I shouldn't even have posted this answer, but at least it contains _some_ pointers towards areas to which the reader can do more research.